# Hugo - Error building site despite not having changed anything

Tags: html, linux, hugo

I am a total amateur and I made a very basic website with Hugo two years ago. Now I would like to make some small changes but when I try to launch the server I get an error, but I didn't change anything.

Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: render of "section" failed: "/home/****/Hugo/********/themes/ga-hugo-theme/layouts/_default/list.html:14:31": execute of template failed: template: _default/list.html:14:31: executing "_default/list.html" at <.URL>: can't evaluate field URL in type page.Page

I'm on linux if that helps. I apologise I'm quite a noob for this stuff.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully you have a backup of the files you *"make some small changes"* (to) . Edit your question to contain the contents of the output from `diff file.orig file.new` .This may be more appropriate to [webmasters.se], but you'll have to read their help section about "what is an on-topic question" and learn how to format any computer `input/output/errMsgs/code` so it is easily copy/paste for readers so that can experience your problem in their local environment. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The thing is that I didn't make any change and the first thing I tried to do was to start the server, which was working the last time I tried (about 2 years ago) and it's not working now :(

Comment: Ah, I see, ... *"but I didn't change anything"*. Doah! ... Well, something has changed on that server right? Are you using a 3rd party web-hosting service? Those enviroments change every 3-4 months so that wouldn't be a surprise if something stopped working. But if you are using your personal serrver, then are you saying you never did an upgrade of the OS, or install other software that might have changed a shared object (some file under `$USR_LIB` or header files in programming like `c-lang `*.h`)? ....

Comment: In any case, your error message doesn't give enough information to identify the source of the problem. Try looking in your web servers log files looking for more details about the failure. (I don't know where they would be) . Again, I recommend that you look at [webmasters.se]'s help for on topic questions to see if this issue is appropriate there. StackOverflow is about fixing `if/then/else` programming code problems, not setup and configuration of systems. If you post to webmasters, include more info about the base OS, the webserver, any containers or VMs you are using. Good luck.

Comment: Arg, I meant `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (not `$USR_LIB`, which often the base directory for shared library objects, i.e. `/usr/lib` . Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the .URL method in .Page was deprecated at some point in the past and the newer version of Hugo wasn't happy about that.

The solution was changing .URL with .RelPermalink

Comment: you can accept your own answer after 48 hrs to gain valuable reputation points. Glad you solved your problem. Good luck with your project!